# Por onde começo para integrar meu jogo com banco de dados?

Tags: android, mysql, web-service, unity-5

Quero que os usuários do meu *Jogo mobile* possam se logar e salvar as informações do game, além de terem a opção de compartilhar algumas informações (por exemplo um personagem criado) para que outros usuários baixem e usem.A parte offline do jogo está praticamente pronto, agora falta criar contas e salvar as informações, entretanto estou perdido nessas questões e não soube por onde começar, pois pelo que pesquisei, seria Web Services, MySQL, Apache, também tenho uma duvida, para os usuários acessarem ou baixarem coisas do meu jogo eu teria que ter meu PC como servidor?

Pode ser que minha pergunta no título não seja exatamente o que eu
esteja procurando aprender. Vocês mais experientes poderiam me dar uma linha de raciocínio a seguir? Eu fiquei a manhã inteira pesquisando mas é tanta informação que eu não soube qual caminho seguir.

Comment: acho q um web service te atende, estude api rest com php por exemplo, dai tu envia os dados via http e salva no banco

Comment: Humm, show. Eu tinha visto algumas coisas sobre isso. Vou tentar seguir por esse caminho.. Em questão de segurança desses dados, tem alguma dica?

Comment: ainda estou estudando essa questão de segurança, to fazendo o basico, envio o login e senha via header do http, e faço essa verificação antes de qualquer ação no banco, e tambem eu armazeno a senha em hash, é uma segurança basica

Comment: Entendi, obrigado Igor vou pegar isso aí pra estudar